# Proper scaling of ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have three elements in my layout, 1 TextView and 2 ImageView. The TextView will be on top and the 2 ImageViews are supposed to be below. I want them to occupy an equivalent amount of spaces where i can align the textview to be in the middle of the space and the imageview to try to occupy both the width and height of the assigned place.

Right now my image is 640 x 480. On some devices, it occupies both the height and width perfectly. However, on other devices with different resolution, it may only take up its width or the height, leaving empty spaces in between. I am using weight to assign the 3 allocated spaces for the 3 elements.

I am newbie when it comes to layout because of the different screen resolution. Is there a way to dynamically reflect the same thing on different resolution devices? Should i not try to allocate spaces for each element via android:layout_weight? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can try in your xml file.  First, I would try using a RelativeLayout to define the appropriate layout parameters.  You can do things like `android:layout_above` and `android:layout_alignleft` to put the images where you want them relative to your parent container and the TextView at the top.   Then use android:scaleType on the ImageViews.  That should put the images where you want them, and then scale them appropriately (check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more info on scaling).

You could also try putting your ImageViews inside FrameLayouts and then put those FrameLayouts inside the LinearLayout as before.  Set the FrameLayout width and height as desired, probably using layout_weight, and then use android:scaleType on the ImageViews.  This method isn't ideal from a performance standpoint because the multiple layout layers can be expensive to draw, especially if this layout is used in a listview or is otherwise repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Linear layout and put orientation as "horizontal" and then you used this below two lines in your textview and imageview. 
    android:layout_weight=1;
    android:layout_width=0;

Comment: No I do not want them to be side by side. I want them to align from top to bottom, taking all the width and height if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use relative layout and inside your onCreate call function to adjust dimensions - something like this

```
private void setUpDimensions(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(dm);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSun);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)iv.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = display.getHeight() * 500 / 800;
    params.width = display.getWidth() * 250 / 1280;

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDesert);
    params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)iv.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = display.getHeight() * 100 / 800;
    params.width = display.getWidth() * 100 / 1280;
    params.leftMargin = display.getWidth() * 207 / 1280;

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageJungle);
    params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)iv.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = display.getHeight() * 150 / 800;
    params.width = display.getWidth() * 150 / 1280;
    params.topMargin = display.getHeight() * 82 / 800;

    params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)newGameButton.getLayoutParams();
    newGameButton.setTextSize(50 * display.getHeight() / 800 / dm.scaledDensity);
    newGameButton.setTypeface(worldData.getTypeface());
    params.leftMargin = display.getWidth() * 430 / 1280;
    params.topMargin = display.getHeight() * 310 / 800;

}
```

I design layout on 1280x800 res and use the numbers like you see above from my layout positions. This ensures that my app supports any resolution

Comment: This is not a good solution.  On Android, xml layouts were designed to allow us the flexibility to have our layouts look reasonable across thousands of devices.   Also, xml layouts help keep your actual code simple, and they adhere to separation of concerns by keeping UI out of your code as much as possible.  You also should not hard code numbers into your layouts.

Comment: My method ensures that every screen resolution will look the same, And this the best way I could do it. If there is any other method that makes activity look the same on any device please feel free to share.